# Was Penelope always supposed to be short-lived on the show?

Tags: character, casting, legacies

In *Legacies*, even being a side character Penelope stand out pretty well and #posie was a famous yuri ship among fans but her arc ended sooner than anyone expected and even ended with a petition of [Bring back Penelope](https://www.change.org/p/the-cw-bring-back-penelope-park-to-legacies-as-a-regular-for-season-2).

Was Penelope always supposed to be a throwaway character as a plot-device or her removal from the show has some behind the scene reasons? Is there any official report about it?